# Use internet from interconnected VM?

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have two centos VMs on the same network. One has an internet connection while the other does not.
Can I use the internet on not connected VM through the one which is connected?
I want to connect to the centos remote repo manager to install JDK.

Can this be done through an SSH tunnel?

Comment: what kind of network (IP4? whats the subnet?). What do you hope to gain from going through a second VM instead of accessing the internet directly (through the router/firewall)?

Comment: The firewall has blocked the internet on the VM I want to access the internet. Yes, it's an ip4 internal network of a data center behind the dc firewall.

Comment: just setup a softwarerouter on the frist VM with a NAT (you'll need to configure a second networkadapter) but chances are the internetaccess will still be blocked by the firewall? how's in charge of the firewall and why does one vm get blocked and the other doesn't?

Comment: Is there a way without setting up external software? There are two firewalls one between the VMS and one at the data center Entry. The firewall listening on the internal network has all ports open among the VMS. Meanwhile, the one at the DC entry point has open internet traffic blocked for some VMS.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh  There is this answer which states using squid.

Comment: yes, you can configure cent OS as a router, there are several howtos out there, search, give it a try and if you run into specific problems you can ask a(nother) question. eg. here: https://linuxhint.com/centos7_router/